# Using twitter REST API v1.1 in django project

Tags: python, django, rest

I am trying to use the twitter APIv1.1 to access and store my tweets in a django database. I have looked through the docs of the API, but there is no direction of how exactly to use its methods or libraries on a project. Most people are using twython, django-twitterly, django-carson, and other apps, to access the twitter API. i would not want to use these since they limit my abilities and i can only perform actions that are inbuilt with a specific app. How do i include the REST API in my django project and use it to access and store my tweets? How do i tell Django to use, say, httplib2(which i want to use for the app)? I tied importing httplib2 and recieved this error: Type Error: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute '**getitem**'" I have looked everywhere for this. Hope you can help.